# How to send parameters from the QML View to the Model with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, arguments, qml

I am trying to send parameters to my Model from the QML View but I'm stuck.

Please note that right now I am able to connect the QML View with the Model, but in order to not repeat my code I want to send some parameter (a QString) from the View and in the Model decide what to send back to the View.

### fileparser.h

```
#ifndef FILEPARSER_H
#define FILEPARSER_H

#include <QObject>

class FileParser : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString file READ file WRITE setFile NOTIFY fileChanged)

public:
    explicit FileParser(QObject *parent = 0);
    FileParser(const QString &file, QObject *parent=0);

    QString file() const;
    void setFile(const QString &file);

    QString fileFinder(QString file);

signals:
    void fileChanged();

private:
    QString m_file;

};

#endif // FILEPARSER_H
```

### fileparser.cpp

```
#include "FileParser.h"

FileParser::FileParser(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

FileParser::FileParser(const QString &file, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), m_file(file)
{
}

QString FileParser::file() const
{
    return m_file;
}

void FileParser::setFile(const QString &file)
{
    if (m_file != file){
        m_file = file;
        emit fileChanged();
    }
}

QString FileParser::fileFinder(QString file)
{
    if (file == “fileA“){
        return “test file A“;
    }
    return “test file B“;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>
#include <QString>

#include "fileparser.h"

QString getFile(QString file)
{
    FileParser *fileParser = new FileParser();
    return fileParser->fileFinder(file);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("_parsedText", getFile(“Default“));

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And finally the QML looks like this:

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    width: 400; height: 400

    Text {
        x: 0; y: parent.height
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: _parsedText // returns "test file B", now how can I send a parameter???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing just the string returned from getFile() as context property. Try to set as context property the whole parser and, in QML code, access to *file* property.

```
// main code
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQuickView view;
  view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
  QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
  FileParser parser("Default");
  ctxt->setContextProperty("parser", &parser);

  view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
  view.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

This way QML code can bind *file* property to other properties and watch for file changes. When you want to change *file* property, just asign a new value to it.

```
// QML code
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
  width: 400; height: 400

  TextInput { // TextInput to allow an user change the text
      x: 0; y: parent.height
      anchors.fill: parent
      text: parser.file // Read and watch for changes
      onTextChanged: parser.file = text // this will call parser.setFile()
  }
}
```